# On a sphere, what is the formula for a great circle in latitude and longitude

Tags: geometry, spherical-trigonometry

Let $\theta$ be latitude, $\phi$ be longitude. I need to find the formula for the great circle passing ($\theta_0$, 0) and (0, $\phi_0$).  This seems a easy and common problem, but I can not find any reference for it to check my answer. The closest problem may be the great-circle navigation problem. Can anyone help?

I guess the answer to be $\frac{\phi \cos \theta}{\phi_0 \cos \theta_0} + \frac{\theta \cos \phi}{\theta_0 \cos \phi_0} = 1$.  But I have difficulty to prove it

Comment: What is your answer? How did you get it?

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Comment: What is your answer?  What does the GC navigation problem tell you?

Comment: I think that the context of the problem is clear enough, right?

Comment: Do you know the [Law of Cosines for Spherical Triangles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines)?

Comment: Context includes what you know, so we know what tools can be used. The link about context I posted before mentions this sort of thing.

Comment: Your work, e.g. your guess and why you think that is the answer, should be in the question. Comments are not the best place for this. You might also describe what the "great-circle navigation problem" is.

Comment: @CPW: I just looked more closely at your guess. The given points do not satisfy that equation.

Comment: $(\theta_0,0):\frac{\phi\cos(\theta)}{\phi_0\cos(\theta_0)}+\frac{\theta\cos(\phi)}{\theta_0\cos(\phi_0)} =\frac1{\cos(\phi_0)}\\ (0,\phi_0):\frac{\phi\cos(\theta)}{\phi_0\cos(\theta_0)}+\frac{\theta\cos(\phi)}{\theta_0\cos(\phi_0)} =\frac1{\cos(\theta_0)}$

Answer (score 3):

Using the [Spherical Law of Cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines), the equation for a great circle with pole $(\theta_p,\phi_p)$ is
$$
\tan(\theta)\tan(\theta_p)+\cos(\phi-\phi_p)=0\tag1
$$
Since $(0,\phi_0)$ satisfies $(1)$, we have
$$
\cos(\phi_0-\phi_p)=0\tag2
$$
We can choose $\phi_p=\phi_0+\frac\pi2$ ($\phi_0-\frac\pi2$ simply leads to the opposite pole). Since $(\theta_0,0)$ satisfies $(1)$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
0
&=\tan(\theta_0)\tan(\theta_p)+\cos(\phi_p)\\
&=\tan(\theta_0)\tan(\theta_p)-\sin(\phi_0)\tag3
\end{align}
$$
therefore, $\tan(\theta_p)=\frac{\sin(\phi_0)}{\tan(\theta_0)}$. Plugging back into $(1)$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
0
&=\tan(\theta)\,\frac{\sin(\phi_0)}{\tan(\theta_0)}+\cos(\phi-\phi_p)\\
&=\tan(\theta)\,\frac{\sin(\phi_0)}{\tan(\theta_0)}+\sin(\phi-\phi_0)\tag4
\end{align}
$$
Thus, we get the equation for the great circle to be
$$
\tan(\theta)\sin(\phi_0)+\tan(\theta_0)\sin(\phi-\phi_0)=0\tag5
$$

Comment: Will the solution be symmetric for $\theta$ and $\phi$?

Comment: What do you mean by symmetric? Do you mean that if $(\theta,\phi)$ is on the great circle, $(\phi,\theta)$ is also?

Comment: The "symmetric" relation that _works_ is:  if $(\theta,\phi)$ lies on the GC, so does $(-\theta,\phi\pm\pi)$.

Comment: @CPW: If you look at $(5)$ and know that $\sin(x+\pi)=-\sin(x)$, that satisfies the symmetry relation that Oscar Lanzi mentions.

Comment: What I mean symmetric is that the equation should stay same if ($\theta$, $\theta_0$) and ($\phi$, $\phi_0$) are exchanged.  For a sphere, these two directions are the same.  I will have a closer look later.

Comment: @CPW: latitude and longitude are not symmetric, why should the formula be the same if $(\theta,\theta_0)$ and $(\phi,\phi_0)$ are exchanged?

Comment: Yes, I realized my mistake.  They are defined differently

Answer (score 2):

You may solve this problem using a **central cylindrical projection.**

- Wrap a cylinder around the equator ($\theta=0$).
- Map points radially from the globe to the cylinder.  Assuming unit radius the point with latitude $\theta$ and longitude $\phi$ is mapped onto $(1,\phi,z=\tan\theta)$ in cylindrical coordinates.
- In general the great circle is mapped to an ellipse on the cylinder, then when the cylinder is cut and unrolled the ellipse becomes a sine wave with the equator as its mean value.

Now the sine wave, having the equator as its midline, will take the form

$z=A\sin(\phi_0-\phi)$

and we just plug in the second point $\phi=0,z=z_0=\tan\theta_0$ to determine $A$.  Thereby

$z=(\tan\theta_0)(\sin(\phi_0-\phi))/(\sin\phi_0)$

All that remains is to put back $z=\tan\theta$ and take the arctangent to get an explicit equation for latitude in terms of longitude:

$\color{blue}{\theta=\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{\tan\theta_0\sin(\phi_0-\phi)}{\sin\phi_0}\right)}$

Answer (score 1):

There are two vectors here, for the point $(\theta_0, 0)$:

$v_1 = (\cos \theta_0 \cos 0 , \cos \theta_0 \sin 0, \sin \theta_0) = (\cos \theta_0, 0, \sin \theta_0)$

and for the point $(0, \phi_0)$:

$v_2 = (\cos 0 \cos \phi_0, \cos 0 \sin \phi_0, \sin 0) = (\cos \phi_0, \sin \phi_0, 0)$

The normal to the great circle passing through these two points is:

$n = v_1 \times v_2 = (-\sin \theta_0 \sin \phi_0, \sin \theta_0 \cos \phi_0, \cos \theta_0 \sin \phi_0)$

A point on the sphere is $P = (\cos \theta \cos \phi, \cos \theta \sin \phi, \sin \theta)$

Hence the equation of the great circle is $P \cdot n = 0$, i.e.,

$ \cos \theta \sin \theta_0 (- \sin \phi_0 \cos \phi + \cos \phi_0 \sin \phi ) + \sin \theta \cos \theta_0 \sin \phi_0 = 0 $

This simplifies to,

$ \cos \theta \sin \theta_0 \sin( \phi - \phi_0)  + \sin \theta \cos \theta_0 \sin \phi_0 = 0 $

And from this last equation, we can express $\theta$ in terms of $\phi$ and have:

$ \theta = - \tan^{-1} \dfrac{ \tan \theta_0 \sin( \phi - \phi_0) }{\sin \phi_0}$